# Extremely casual way to make requests to very close friends

Tags: slang, casual

How does one make a very casual "request" to a good friend. I know that the て form is used to make a request that is fairly casual, but it doesn't sound "casual enough". For example, 食べて, would probably sound like 'please' eat it (a very soft please) and ptobably isnt said in very casual situations. To give a more concrete example, lets say I am with a close friend, and what I really want to say is "come on, dont be a wimp and just eat it bruh" or something along that line. In such cirxumstances, I would probably say...blah blah blah...... and finally食べてよ。I should also ask if its ok for both genders to use it. But that (at least to me) doesnt really sound casual does it, so I am wondering what is the most appropriate way to say this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In no particular order, we do say these:

- 「食べなよ」
- 「食べな」
- 「食べて**み**」 ← gaining popularity in recent years.
- 「食{く}ってみ」 mostly masculine
- 「食べちゃえよ」 mostly masculine
- 「食べちゃいなよ」
- 「食{く}っちゃえよ」 mostly masculine
- 「食べちゃったら？」
- 「食{く}っちゃいな」 mostly masculine

The ones that use 「食{く}う」 instead of 「食{た}べる」 would naturally be uttered mostly by male speakers.

Thus, to a friend that is hesitating to try a food item, you might say:

- 「ごちゃごちゃ言ってないで、（一回{いっかい} or 一口{ひとくち}）食ってみ！」

↑ Change the 「ない」 to 「ねえ」 and it will sound even more casual.

- 「能書{のうが}きタレてねえで、早{はや}く食{く}っちゃえよ！」

I have probably gone too casual.  Point is that if your Japanese is basically textbook-ish (which is often the case with Japanese-learners), uttering just one extremely casual sentence learned from a native speaker will only make you look weird.